# Replace image if default is unavailable - Tumblr

Tags: html, css, tumblr

So I'm trying to get a default image to show on an audio post if there is no image available because sometimes people don't upload an image when they upload an audio post. I've tried looking all over but I don't know the exact wording for this effect and all I could find was how to replace a "broken image" but it isn't broken, just missing. You can view the blog here: http://auzx.tumblr.com/

As you can see there is a normal audio post with the image uploaded and one that I uploaded w/o album art to see if I could figure out how to add a default image.

This is the audio code from the HTML portion and you can view the source using ctrl+u if you need to look at the css

```
{block:Audio}
<div class="playbox"><div class="playbutton">{block:AudioPlayer}{AudioPlayerBlack}{/block:AudioPlayer}</div></div>
{block:AlbumArt}<img src="{AlbumArtURL}" class="cover"/>{/block:AlbumArt}
{block:Artist}<div class="artist">Artist: {Artist}</div>{/block:Artist}
{block:TrackName}<div class="trackname">Title: {TrackName}</div>{/block:TrackName}
{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
{/block:Audio}
```

Sorry if this is something really obvious like I stated before I don't know the exact wording or termonology for this!!

Comment: If you can't add a condition to check that the album art exists then you could always show a default image, and position the album art on top of that using CSS. If it doesn't exist the default image will show. If it does exist only the album art will be visible.

Comment: Ah I didn't even think of the second thing! Thank you!